# Applying backward shift operator on the composition operators on Hardy spaces

Tags: reference-request, operator-theory, operator-norms

Let $H^2$ be the Hardy space. Let $K_\theta=H^2\ominus\theta H^2$, $\theta$ inner. Let $S$ be the shift operator on $H^2$. Its compression to $K_\theta$ is $S_\theta$.

My question: do we have in the literature a discussion related to $ S^{*^n}C_\varphi$ or  $ S^{*^n}_\theta C_\varphi$.  $C_\varphi$ is the composition operator on the Hardy space.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

May be this helpful
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.5172.pdf

Composition operator on model spaces
Yurii I Lyubarskii, Eugenia Malinnikova
Journal-ref: Recent trends in analysis, 149-157, Theta Ser. Adv. Math., Theta, Bucharest, 2013
.